# Form "Not responding" if it has not been shown before

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that watches a directory for changes. When a file (a log file) is created, it analyses its contents, writes the results in a form (that exists already and has been initialized, although may be currently hidden) and finally shows this form to the user.

When the application starts, just an icon is shown in the task bar. The main method just creates the icon in the task bar and initializes the class that watches/analyses and controls the form with the results.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    NotificationIcon notificationIcon = new NotificationIcon();
    notificationIcon.notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    if (notificationIcon.Init()) {
        MainForm = ResultForm.GetInstance();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

"ResultForm" is the class I just mentioned before and has the following methods relevant to the problem:

```
public static ResultForm GetInstance() {
    // _this is an attribute from the class. Is used to work always
    // with just one instance of the classe
    if (_this==null)
        _this= new ResultForm();

    return _this;
}

private ResultForm() {
    // initialization of the GUI form
    InitializeComponent();

    [...]

    // watcher for the log files
    logsWatcher= new FileSystemWatcher(LOGFILES_FOLDER);
    logsWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(NewFile);
    logsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents=true;
    logsWatcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
}

private void NewFile (object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    // make sure the file is of the correct type
    [...]
    // perform some analysis on the file
    [...]
    // update the contents in the form (some TreeViews and labels)
    [...]

    // show the form to the user
    _this.Show();
}
```

And now comes the problem. If the application starts, a file is analysed and the main form has not been shown yet, it will be shown as "Not responding" when the analysis is complete, although everything has been already done. If a new file is created after, it will be successfully analysed, although the form will stay in this "Not responding" state.

HOWEVER, if the form has been opened at least once before since the application started (say, you double-clicked on the icon, the form was shown and you closed it (or left it open, it does not matter)), everything will work smoothly.

As a workaroud, I can modify the main with the following two lines (before the `Run()` method), so the form will be shown at least once before any file comes:

```
MainForm.Show();
MainForm.Hide();
```

(I hide it back because it should not be visible until an analysis has been performed or the user has explictly clicked on the icon.)
Other than that, there is no difference in the program: the work done is the same and the form is always shown once everything is done. I have made sure with the debugger that the end of the method is reached during execution.

How can I solve this problem without the mentioned workaround?

I have tried creating a thread for the analysis, using `Application.DoEvents()` or blocks of code similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360944/force-gui-update-from-ui-thread). In the best of the cases, the form shows all its contents properly, but stays in a "Not responding" state. I have also tried to just leave the `Show()` call in the method with exactly the same results, which tells me it is not a problem of heavy load, but of something I may be doing wrong.

**EDIT**
Since @thecoon requested it, I have uploaded a small project that reproduces the problem. It has been done with SharpDevelop, in case you also use it.
--> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1153417/test.zip

There is a small explanation in the Main() method.

Comment: Can you upload somewhere a minimal sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Have you tried doing the analysis of logs in a separate thread? This is the common approach to prevent the freeze of UI

Comment: undefined, as I mention in the last paragraph, yes, I have tried that, but the result is the same.
@thecoon, I will try to upload a sample somewhere as soon as I have time

Comment: Your Main() method is missing the [STAThread] attribute.

Comment: It is in the line exactly before the declaration of Main()

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect this is a threading issue, one caused by how you start your ResultForm, and also how you've set the FileSystemObjects [synchronization object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject.aspx).

The synchronization object effectively chooses the thread to marshall the updates on. In this instance, it's also the thread you are trying to show the GUI on, so you might have run into a good old blocking operation, or there may just be a large number of file system events causing your thread to context switch back and forth rapidly.

As a starter, try this instead:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    NotificationIcon notificationIcon = new NotificationIcon();
    notificationIcon.notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    if (notificationIcon.Init()) {
        MainForm = new ResultForm();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

Note that we now marshal the ResultForm to the UI thread directly.

And change ResultForm this way (there's no real need for it to be a singleton, too):

```
public ResultForm() {
    // initialization of the GUI form
    InitializeComponent();

    [...]
    this.Load += ResultForm_Load;
}


protected void ResultForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // watcher for the log files
    logsWatcher= new FileSystemWatcher(LOGFILES_FOLDER);
    logsWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(NewFile);
    logsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents=true;
    //Don't set the synchronization object - now all events from the FileSystemWatcher will be marshalled on a background thread
    Visible = false; //Hide the form if you want or minimize to tray or similar.
}

private void NewFile (object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {

    if(InvokeRequired){
        //Ensures the file system events are marshalled back to the GUI thread
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {NewFile(source, e);}));
        return;
    }

    // make sure the file is of the correct type
    [...]
    // perform some analysis on the file
    [...]
    // update the contents in the form (some TreeViews and labels)
    [...]

    // show the form to the user
    Show(); //or Visible = true;
}
```

By not setting the synchronization object on the FileSystemWatcher to be the form, you ensure that all File System event marshalling will happen in ThreadPool threads. When a New event is raised, we just remember to marshal back to the UI thread by checking InvokeRequired and calling the form's Invoke method if necessary.

UPDATE

The main reason is that, by calling either MainForm.Show directly or via Application.Run(MainForm), you push the form onto the thread the message loop is on.

If you run the app using your original code, when `NewFile` is called, `Application.MessageLoop` is false.

If you use your workaround, or the standard way of showing the application, as per my example, `Application.MessageLoop` is true.

My best guess here is that the form is deadlocking because the FileSystemWatcher (which, as it's using the form as a synchronization object in the original example, which effectively means it calls `BeginInvoke` on the form). However, it could also be a huge variety of other issues; Form.Show() is actually hanging on the method `FPushMessageLoop` - it is caught in an infinite loop.

@HansPassant or @HenkHolterman have both posted extensively around these issues - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833002/1073107 for example. Note that if you show a splashscreen or similar on start up, then all initialization works as expected, and NewFile completes successfully; in short, it looks like you *have* to show something at app startup if you want your process to work. I don't think this is a bad thing; the user can see an app has started and is now running in the tray, for example, and you can be sure you wont run into this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @dash.
I have tried what you wrote. Although there is a "Visible = false" in the load method, the form will anyway be shown with the `Application.Run(MainForm)` call. Unfortunately, this is not what i am looking for for 2 reasons: the window is shown to the user when it shouldn't and, since the form is being shown, the behaviour of the application is the same I got with the Show()&Hide() methods in the main.

Nevertheless, the `if(InvokeRequiered)` block as well as what you explained is important and I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Solem Get the application working first - ignore the fact that you want to hide and show the form - you can do that later. The thing to do first is to establish the source of the freeze; if you structure the application as per my answer, and put a breakpoint or logging in NewFile to see if it's being called continously. What does "// update the contents in the form (some TreeViews and labels)
" actually do, for example?

Comment: I thought I had wrote it before but I was wrong. The application was working properly with your solution (as it does with my workaround). I put a breakpoint at the begining of "NewFile" and I saw it was called twice: one in which the InvokeRequires block is executed and a second one in which it is not. The rest of the code i didn't write just parses the logfile, changes the Text property of some labels and builds a tree with the information found. This part has been tested before and works properly

Comment: @Solem; that's great! Then to achieve your hiding effect, you could consider just minimizing to the system tray: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-sharp-winforms-app

Comment: my doubt is still unresolved and your solution, although perfectly valid, is just doing (apart form the Invoke) the same my workaround does: show the window and minimize (hide) it. I still want to understand why everything works properly if the window has been shown before and why it freezes otherwise =/

Comment: @Solem - some extra details. Not a definitive answer, but gives you some more to think about.